# Kubernetes: How to pass pipe character in readiness probe command

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am having an issue with passing a pipe character `|` in readiness probe command.

I want to have a probe command:

`curl --silent http://localhost:8080/actuator/health | grep --quiet -e '^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'`

Here is how I have defined the probe:

```
# kubectl get pod my_pod -o yaml

readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - curl
    - --silent
    - http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
    - '|'
    - grep
    - --quiet
    - -e
    - '''^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'''
```

Readiness probe fails with a message:

> Readiness probe failed: curl: **option --quiet: is unknown curl**: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

The error can be reproduce when command is executed without pipe character `|`:

`curl --silent http://localhost:8080/actuator/health grep --quiet -e '^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'`

For some reason pipe is not interpreted by Kubernetes.

Can you please help me with passing pipe in deployment?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't run a shell to process commands on its own; it just runs them directly.  The closest equivalent in a shell would be

```sh
curl '--silent' 'http://...' '|' 'grep' ...
```

That is, `|` here doesn't split two separate commands, because that's shell syntax; without a shell it becomes another parameter to `curl`, as do all of the words after it.

You need to provide the shell wrapper yourself:

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - curl --silent http://localhost:8080/actuator/health | grep --quiet -e '^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'
```

You can use alternate YAML syntax to make this a little more readable.  (`>` means to fold following lines into a single string; `-` means to strip leading and trailing whitespace.

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - >-
         curl --silent http://localhost:8080/actuator/health |
         grep --quiet -e '^{\"status\"\:\"UP\".*}$'
```