# livenessProbe seems not to be executed

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

A container defined inside a deployment has a `livenessProbe` set up: by definition, it calls a remote endpoint and checks, whether response contains useful information or an empty response (which should trigger the pod's restart).

The whole definition is as follows (I removed the further checks for better clarity of the markup):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fc-backend-deployment
  labels:
    name: fc-backend-deployment
    app: fc-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fc-backend-pod
      app: fc-test
  template:
    metadata:
      name: fc-backend-pod
      labels:
        name: fc-backend-pod
        app: fc-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fc-backend
        image: localhost:5000/backend:1.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4044
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "dev"
        - name: REDIS_HOST
          value: "redis"
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - curl -X GET $BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT/api/v3/stats | head -c 30 > /app/out.log
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          failureThreshold: 12
          periodSeconds: 10
```

I also tried putting the command into an array:

```yaml
command: ["sh", "-c", "curl -X GET $BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT/api/v3/stats", "|", "head", "-c", "30", ">", "/app/out.log"]
```

and splitting into separate lines:

```yaml
- /bin/bash
- -c
- curl
- -X
- GET
- $BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT/api/v3/stats
- |
- head
- -c
- "30"
- >
- /app/out.log
```

and even like this:

```yaml
command:
  - |
      curl -X GET $BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT/api/v3/stats | head -c 30 > /app/out.log
```

All attempts were made with and without `(/bin/ba)sh -c` - with the same result.

But, as you're reading this, you already know that none of these worked.

I know it by `exec`'ing into running container and trying to find the `/app/out.log` file - it wasn't present any time I watched the directory contents. It looks like the probe gets never executed.

The command run inside running container works just fine: data gets fetched and written to the specified file.

What might be causing the probe not to get executed?

Comment: Please take a look at this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932210/kubernetes-how-to-pass-pipe-character-in-readiness-probe-command ). Most probably the error is that you cnanot use | the way you are using it.

Comment: Yep, that was it: rewriting the command as: `- sh \ - -c \ - >- \   curl -X GET ...` solves the issue! Please consider adding this as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great! And I added the whole thing as an answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `exec` type of probes, Kubernetes will **not** run a shell to process the command, it will just run the command directly. This means that you can only use a single command and that the `|` character is considered just another parameter of your `curl`.

To solve the problem, you need to use `sh -c` to exec shell code, something like the following:

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - >-
              curl -X GET $BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST:$BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT/api/v3/stats |
              head -c 30 > /app/out.log
```